# Locating flash chip for dumping firmware

Tags: pcb, flash, reverse-engineering, firmware

I'm trying to dip my toes into reversing and thought that dumping and inspecting the firmware running on this controller/pcb would be fun learning, however I'm having trouble locating the flash chip. Any advice where to start?

Back story: this is a IR device to regulate different air conditioners via sms. I've sampled the IR codes and are running it on a esp8266 but the results sometimes vary when sending the codes, hence why I would like to inspect the firmware.

[image: Back view of pcb]

[image: Front view of pcb]

Comment: it's inside the 28 pin IC ... there are no other places it could be

Comment: ... and the chip part number has been sanded off.

Comment: If the developers are worth their money, the MCU will have some sort of locking mechanism active, that'll prevent you from reading out it's contents.

Comment: There's only one chip so it has everything inside - not only the flash memory but also the MCU. I would bet it is some PIC microcontroller. You can try to find some matches by pin count and "important" pins locations like RX/TX etc.

Comment: But if they went through the trouble of sanding down chip markings, I'm sure it will have lock bits enabled so you won't be able to read the stuff

Comment: Does that USB port do anything when attached to a computer? Because the layout doesn’t look very usb to me. Might be a programming port in disguise

Comment: Welp, I feared that, and as the markings are sanded off this might be quite the undertaking. Nothing happens plugged into a computer. No output at all from dmesg. Thanks for all the suggestions guys and girls!

Comment: @arrayCobbler it's a soic28 with what looks to be centered power lines and in circuit programming/debugging lines to the top portions. I'd check the usual hobby suspects for a compatible pinout - STM, PIC and ATMEGA. Shame there's no clock crystal, that would narrow it down further.